# MapReduce Processing failed due to VM limit exceeded

Tags: arrays, hadoop, mapreduce, limit, skew

MapReduce Processing is failing due to VM limit exceeded.
All that we found is data skewness, 
Are there any rational behind MapReduce getting failed due to data skewness ?

Comment: Hello,
Can you provide a stacktrace of the error you get?

Comment: Its not possible to provide the stack trace for now. I did reinstall the OS. If it occurs again, I'll surely post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is skewed badly enough, then that means one mapper or reducer will have to process more data.  Which means it will need more memory and run longer.  If you've set your cluster's Node Manager memory aggressively, you could easily swamp a VM or node.

It's a common problem and big enough issue that people have written papers on it.

- [Managing Skew in Hadoop](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kair/papers/bala.pdf)
- [A Survey on Data Skew Mitigating Techniques
  in Hadoop MapReduce Framework](http://www.ijcsmc.com/docs/papers/July2016/V5I7201639.pdf)
- [A Survey on Hadoop MapReduce Framework and the Data Skew Issues](http://www.ijsret.org/pdf/121093.pdf)